# Why isn't this regex working in my Nifi workflow?

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I'd like to extract some text from an excel file (after ConvertToCsv and SplitText processors).
After the split processor, some of the lines are like this : "Compétences clés : competence1, competence2, competence3" with a list between commas. I just want to get the list, to split it afterwards.

I have tested this simple regex on Regex101 : "Compétences clés : (.*)" which takes everything after these terms, so it returns the list.
But when I try it in NiFi, even when the previous steps are working, I don't get anything in my out flowfiles.

Am I doing something wrong in the processors's configuration ? What am I missing ?

[NiFi workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hAEL.png)

[ExtractText properties window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4CVy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found where the problem comes from. Apparently it's an encoding issue and the accents are not properly read in my dataflow, that's why "Compétences clés" matched nothing. But when trying with "Comp.tences cl.s", it works. For the following, I have indeed used the ReplaceText processor to get the attributes values.

Comment: Please mark your answer as the correct answer, so people will find easier what was the problem and what was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, the workflow image attached does not have complete flow so I am not sure what happens after ExtractText processor.

Also you mentioned that you are not getting anything in out flow files from ExtractText processor. So I assumed that you want the result of the regex expression to be a new flow file which is list. - Answer is based on this; If this is not something you want, please let me know.

> ExtractText Processor: Evaluates one or more Regular Expressions against the content of a FlowFile. The results of those Regular Expressions are assigned to FlowFile Attributes.The name of the property maps to the Attribute Name into which the result will be placed.

As per the description, result of the regex is stored in a flow file attribute; 'regex' in your case and actual flow file with modified attributes is routed to downstream processor.

To work with this attribute value as a flow file, create a new flow file which has only the attribute value as content using ReplaceText processor.

[NiFi Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRtDc.png)

[ReplaceText Processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGSrk.png)

On success, ReplaceText processor will send the updated flow file to the downstream processor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This doesn't resolve my issue though, because nothing is coming from my ExtractTest processor in the first place, so the step you added doesn't have anything in its input. What doesn't work is really the ExtractText step, and I don't know why nothing gets out. Don't hesitate if you need more information about it.